# Usage of MATIP (Mapping of Airline traffic over internet protocol) in IBM Integration bus

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Does IBM integration Bus 10.0.0.X support MATIP protocol. Does it have a MATIP adapter ,can you point me to some documentation on the same. I found this link to this PDF document on the web http://docplayer.net/49287265-Websphere-message-broker-airline-technology-matip-adapter.html.

Comment: I just tried a simple Google search for "IIB MATIP" and found a developer works article that discusses how to use this with IIB.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc ,this helped. They don't have the sample code available but it definitely gives some idea